# filter on one column and rank on another without grouping in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame having 4 columns student_name, total_marks, is_shortlisted, rank

I wanted to rank rows on the basis of the total_marks column where the is_shortlisted = "Y".

sample input data :

```
name     total_marks   is_shortlisted
Aman       67              Y
Nitin      89              Y
Ankur      76              Y
Mohit      56              N
Ashish     64              Y
```

sample output data :

```
name     total_marks   is_shortlisted  rank 
Aman       67              Y            3
Nitin      89              Y            1
Ankur      76              Y            2
Mohit      56              N            nan
Ashish     64              Y            4
```

Comment: How are we supposed to answer your question with knowing anything about your data? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @user3483203  Please check now.I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `loc` with `rank`:

```
df.assign(rank=df.loc[df.is_shortlisted.eq('Y')].total_marks.rank(ascending=False))

     name  total_marks is_shortlisted  rank
0    Aman           67              Y   3.0
1   Nitin           89              Y   1.0
2   Ankur           76              Y   2.0
3   Mohit           56              N   NaN
4  Ashish           64              Y   4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you tell me what should I write if I want to copy df to new data frame and only rows where is_shorlisted=Y . I need a seprate copy without linking with old one.

Comment: @priya the code that I posted returns a copy, it does not modify the dataframe, so simply do something like `df1 = CODE HERE` and you will have a copy of the dataframe :)